# How can I check network connectivity on the TVOS using Swift 4.0?

Tags: swift

I'm on Apple TV and my app needs to check if there is internet connection, on the IOS I found the good reachability but for the TV no avail.

If you know how can I check if there is internet connection I would be glad.

I tried the suggested on this link https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/networking/how-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-nwpathmonitor

import Network
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()

But I got a compilation problem regarding NWPathMonitor class
'NWPathMonitor' is only available on iOS 12.0 or newer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this framework instead:

https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

It supports tvOS from version 9.0 upwards. You can either make single reachability requests with it or register a notifier to get informed, when reachability changes.